# Правильный перенос слова "тыква"

Tags: орфография

Как правильно перенести слово "тыква"?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно: тык-ва или ты-ква.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, как минимум, в конце вопроса ставится вопросительный знак.
А вообще, что не понятого? В слове всего два слога: "тык-ва". Неужели, есть еще какие-то варианты?)))

Comment: По современным правилам перенос "ты-ква" допустим, более того по фонетическим и историческим причинам может представляться даже предпочтительным.

Answer (score 0):

Да, именно такой ответ

Comment: Какой именно???